# I am getting the path of an newly added image to directory, but cv2.imread() printing type <class 'NoneType'> in python

Tags: python, opencv, path

```py
import os
import cv2

path = 'C:\\Users\\rishi\\Documents\\Sudoky-Solver\\Sudoky-Solver\\test'

list = os.listdir(path)

def newest(path):

    files = os.listdir(path)
    paths = [os.path.join(path, basename) for basename in files]
    return max(paths, key=os.path.getctime)

while True:

    list2 = os.listdir(path)
    if list2 != list:
        imgpath = newest(path)
        img = cv2.imread(str(imgpath).replace('\\', '/'))
        print(type(img))
        list = list2
```

When I run the code, the code gives error

Output:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imread+none

Comment: look at the path you calculate there. what does it say? what does `os.path.exists(...)` say about that path?

Answer (score 0):

You get <class 'NoneType'> only when the path is incorrect. Also, sometimes you have to pass your image path as raw input (r'D:.....') because you may have a /t or so in the path. Just print the paths and check them first. :)